# How to implement 2d Rotary Position Embedding in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, transformer

The original RoPE paper suggests that the Rotary Position Embedding it describes can easily be extended to two or more dimensions: 3.2.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.09864 . I'm trying to find a PyTorch implementation of this and I can't; I can only find implementations for a 1D embedding. Is anyone aware of any 2D implementations in PyTorch (or another framework, which I could translate to PyTorch)?

Comment: Not an expert in rotary embeddings or vision transformers but, after Googling, I bumbped into the term "axial rotary embeddings" and into these two pytorch libraries that support them: [rotary-embedding-torch](https://github.com/lucidrains/rotary-embedding-torch#axial-rotary-embeddings), [axial-positional-embedding](https://github.com/lucidrains/axial-positional-embedding). Is it what you were looking for?